# Default opener not honored?

Tags: finder, defaults, macos

I have TextEdit set as default opener for `*.ged` but a double-click or a click in Dock Downloads fan says no default exists.  **Cause?  Fix?**

UPDATE:
After seeing *jaume*’s comment, I created an **empty** `testing.ged` and opened in Finder a directory that contained a non empty `HHH.ged`.  I did Get Info on `HHH.ged` and changed the default from TextEdit to BBEdit.  The I used `testing.ged` to change it back.  Double-click now works.  Since the problem did not exist one week ago, I’m going to blame it on another complaint I made to Apple long ago: almost every update of MacOS or IOS changes preferences.  MacOS 12.5.1 was installed shortly before this happened.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Reported to Apple as bug.  But bugs reported years ago are still open, so …

Comment: I could reproduce your issue and solve it setting the default app for *.ged files to another app, opening it and then changing it back to TextEdit. Could you try it and report back?

Comment: Well, that's definitely an answer for "Fix?" and I’ve taken a guess at answering "Cause?"